# "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" error in java

Tags: java

**This program is supposed to find Max and Min in an array,
but it send error:**
 "*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 23
    at Mine_EnhancedForLoop.main(Mine_EnhancedForLoop.java:17)*"
**Does anyone know, what the problem is?**

```
public class Mine_EnhancedForLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            int[] array1 = {23, 98, 10, 1, 45, 2, 7, 90};

            int max = array1[0];
            int min = array1[0];

            for (int i : array1){

                if (array1[i] > max)
                    max = array1[i];

                else if (array1[i] < min)
                    min = array1[i];
            }
            System.out.println("Maximum is: " + max);
            System.out.println("Minimum is: " + min);
    }
}
```

Comment: Example #4725 of why Java is not the same as JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `for (int i : array1)`, `i` is a value contained in the array, not an index of the array. Therefore `array1[i]` will throw the exception you got whenever `i >= array1.length` (which is the case for most of the values in your input array).

If you don't need to know the index of the highest and lowest values, this will work :

```
        for (int i : array1) {
            if (i > max)
                max = i;
            else if (i < min)
                min = i;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i : array1)
```

`i` gives the element of array not the index of array

So in the first iteration

```
if(array1[23] > max)  //gave you ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException 23
```

you can do

```
 int[] array1 = {23, 98, 10, 1, 45, 2, 7, 90};

 int max = array1[0];
 int min = array1[0];

 int i=0;

 while(i< array1.length){

      if (array1[i] > max)
           max = array1[i];

     else if (array1[i] < min)
           min = array1[i];

         i++;
      }
 System.out.println("Maximum is: " + max);
 System.out.println("Minimum is: " + min);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/cPhBU2)

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate the array elements as:

```
for (int i=0; i<array1.length; i++){
    if (array1[i] > max)
        max = array1[i];
    else if (array1[i] < min)
        min = array1[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the for loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] > max) {
        max = array1[i];
    } else if (array1[i] < min)
        min = array1[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because variable `i` contains 23 when making the comparison here `if (array1[i] > max)`, hence array1[23] gave the exception.

Loop over the array instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] > max)
        max = array1[i];

    else if (array1[i] < min)
        min = array1[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is much easier to use Java 8 streams:

```
int[] array1 = {23, 98, 10, 1, 45, 2, 7, 90};
System.out.println("Maximum is: " + Arrays.stream(array1).max().getAsInt());
System.out.println("Minimum is: " + Arrays.stream(array1).min().getAsInt());
```